# Allowing access to a submit button, but not the public

Tags: php, html, security, web

I have a public facing site that uses Wordpress.  We have a single custom page for online applications to our service, but have discovered that if you know the name of one of the files on the server you can view anything by guessing the correct html link for the file.

These applications are stored online as a backup to the ones that are emailed by the submit form.  We would like to make it possible for the HTML in the submit button to still save the applications, but not for people to access the subdirectory where they are stored.  I can create a script to download and delete the applications on a schedule so that they are *mostly* cleared out, but there will always be the potential for someone to guess at the right moment and see the applications, or even brute force script downloads.

Comment: Define "public"...

Comment: store your files outside the web server published folders. Create a script that authenticates the user then dynamically outputs the file.  See  example at 
   https://serverfault.com/questions/316814/php-serve-a-file-for-download-without-providing-the-direct-link

Comment: There's no need to authenticate the user as the public (anyone in the planet) can't actually see the application once they hit submit, it gets emailed to us, and then the .html output of the form gets saved to a subdir called applications.  We download the applications every few days manually and save them to the server, just in case we need to historically refer to one.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using an htaccess and htpassword in conjunction with a blank index.html.  That prompts for a supercomplicated password and fails out to a 401 error.